# Keycloak custom identity provider configuration page

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-spi

In older versions of Keycloak (<= 19.0.3) it was possible to create your own HTML templates for custom identity providers by packaging them under `theme-resources/resources/partials` and providing them as part of the identity provider jar.

Keycloak 21.0.0 came out with the new admin console, and the trick with setting `--features-disabled=admin2` makes it completely unavailable. As the result of these changes in newer versions of Keycloak it is not possible to configure the custom providers, as it can be seen in the images attached below.

How can one achieve the same result in newer versions of Keycloak, so that custom templates get displayed? Is the only way is to fork the complete project and add the desired templates somewhere in [js folder](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/js)?

[image: The old settings page]

[image: The new setting page]

Comment: the current workaround is importing realm from old instance with preconfigured provider, since the backing keycloak codebase wasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Create new account theme with custom partials. Package it up in theme.jar and add to providers. Override the default one (account2 or account3) to use your custom account theme (my-account-theme).